# JQuery Function Only Printing out Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, append

I'm writing a function meant to append the contents of a text field on a webpage to a list, so that another part of my HTML can render the list contents above the text field. The field and button appear and are responsive, but the only thing that get's printed out is "undefined" rather than the contents of the text field. This is the javascript function:

```
<sp:script>


$('#append').on('click', function () {
   var text = $('#new-text').val();
   var li = '<li>' + text + '</li>';
   $('#target-list').append(li);
});

</sp:script>
```

And this is the code for rendering the text, the text field, and the button:

```
    <!-- adding text -->
        <div class="tab-content"> <!-- begin div -->
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">

                    <ul id ="target-list"> <!-- begin rendering existing text -->
                        <g:each var="newText" in="${instance.newTexts}">
                            <li class ="list-item">
                                ${newText} 
                            <input type="hidden" name="newText" value=${newText}"/>
                            </li>
                        </g:each>
                    </ul> <!-- end rendering existing text -->
                    <!-- enter text field start -->
                        <input class="form-control required" type="text" id="new-email" placeholder="Enter additional email addresses"/>


                        <!-- enter text field end -->
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <!-- begin code for add button -->  
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-green" title="Add mew text"
                        id = "append">

                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button> <!--  end button div -->
                </div>
                               
            </div>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Spell the ID correctly and wrap in `$(function() {...}`

Comment: There is no element with an id of `new-text`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything with an id of 'new-text'

Answer (score 1):

Your input does not have the id '#new-text'. This would cause `$('#new-text').val()` to be undefined. Try adding the ID.

```
<input id="new-text" type="hidden" name="newText" value=${newText}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

your ID isn't `new-text`, it's `new-email`

```
$('#append').on('click', function () {
   var text = $('#new-email').val();
   var li = '<li>' + text + '</li>';
   $('#target-list').append(li);
});
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is actually the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to an ID 'new-text' which does not exist. Check your HTML and make sure the IDs you are calling in jQuery exist.